# Interactive PDF Form Validation

Tags: forms, validation, pdf, interactive

I'm hoping someone can help me with a challenge I am unable to find a solution for. I need to create an interactive form within a PDF document. One of the main issues is that  I have 3 fields where I require an Integer input from the user. After all 3 fields are filled out, I need to ensure that the result is equal to 100%. Is this something that is even possible?

I hope my question makes sense. On a general level, I suppose I need to know whether I can apply programmatic validation to a PDF Form Field, and be able to determine the value of other fields within that same PDF document.

Thank you kindly in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JavaScript for Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html) in order to achieve this.